# Deleting old files using cron job in Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2, cron

I was setting up a cron job where I wanted to delete log files older than 1 day. The command to do this is as below. I am doing this on a AWS Linux EC2 instance.

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -delete
```

But what I want to achieve is I want to exclude `.log` files from getting deleted and want to just delete the files with `.gz` extension. Can any body let me know how I achieve that exclusion in find command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look for ***.gz** files and delete them.

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -name '*.gz' -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -delete
```

Before deleting, just list the files to make sure you are deleting the correct ones.

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -name '*.gz' -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -print
```

Comment: How will I achieve multiple extension here? for example if I want to delete .gz and .out too?

Comment: Also I get this warning "find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -name, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments." any idea to get rid of this warning?

Comment: For multiple extensions, explore `-regex` option of `find`. I usually pipe the output to `egrep`

Answer (score 0):

Print all files selected as below:

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -name '*.gz' -mindepth 1 -mtime +1
```

Above files can be deleted as below:

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -name '*.gz' -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -exec rm{} \
```